# Issue with vector<bool> and printf

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    vector<bool> a;
    a.push_back(false);
    int t=a[0];
    printf("%d %d\n",a[0],t);
    return 0;
}
```

This code give output "5511088 1". I thought it would be "0 0".

Anyone know why is it?

Comment: And thus we learn that `printf` isn't type-safe :-) Instead, say `std::cout << a[0] << " " << t << "\n";`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `%d` format specifier is for arguments the size of integers, therefore the `printf` function is expecting two arguments both the size of an `int`. However, you're providing it with one argument that isn't an `int`, but rather a special object returned by `vector<bool>` that is convertible to `bool`.

This is basically causing the `printf` function to treat random bytes from the stack as part of the values, while in fact they aren't.

The solution is to cast the first argument to an `int`:

```
printf("%d %d\n", static_cast<int>(a[0]), t);
```

An even better solution would be to prefer streams over `printf` if at all possible, because unlike `printf` they are type-safe which makes it impossible for this kind of situation to happen:

```
cout << a[0] << " " << t << endl;
```

And if you're looking for a type-safe alternative for `printf`-like formatting, consider using the [Boost Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) library.

Comment: Almost but vector<bool> is special and operator[] on a vector<bool> does not return a bool, it returns an object of a type convertable to a bool, and printf cannot do that conversion as it's not type safe. But your cast forces the conversion.

Answer (score 3):

`%d` format specifier is for `int` type. So, try -

```
cout << a[0] << "\t" << t << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

The key to the answer is that vector isn't really a vector of bools.  It's really a vector of proxy objects, which are translatable into ints & bools.  This allows each bool to be stored as a single bit, for greater space efficiency (at the cost of speed efficiency), but causes a number of problems like the one seen here.   This requirement was voted into the C++ Standard in a rash moment, and I believe most committee members now believe it was a mistake, but it's in the Standard and we're kind-of stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is triggered by [the specialization for bool of vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sequence_container_(C%2B%2B)&oldid=767869909#Specialization_for_bool).

> The Standard Library defines a specialization of the vector template for bool. The description of this specialization indicates that the implementation should pack the elements so that every bool only uses one bit of memory. *This is widely considered a mistake*.

Basically **`std::bool` use 1 bit instead of 1 byte**, so you face undefined behavior regarding printf.

**If you are really willing to use `printf`**, you can solve this issue by defining `std::bool` as char and print it as integer %d (implicit conversion, 1 for true and 0 for false).

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#define bool char // solved

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    vector<bool> a;
    a.push_back(false);
    int t = a[0];
    printf("%d %d\n", a[0], t);
    return 0;
}
```